How to send emails from Microsoft Workspace Email without disabling security defaults?
I have a simple sendMail function that is supposed to send emails from my Microsoft workspace email through a Node.js backend.
async function sendMail() {
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
        auth: {
            user: 'no-reply@custom-domain.com',
            pass: '****',
        },
        tls: {
            ciphers: "TLSv1.2",
        },
        port: 587,
    });
    return await transporter.sendMail({
        from: 'no-reply@custom-domain.com',
        to: ['to@example.com'],
        subject: 'subject',
        text: 'Welcome aboard...!',
    });
}

However, it is erroring out with the following error: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, user is locked by your organization's security defaults policy. Contact your administrator.
Now, I do not want to disable security defaults. What is the best and safest way to implement this?, and is the Microsoft Graph API a viable option here?, or anything else?

a) is no-reply@custom-domain.com the right account? Sounds unusual. b) do you have an administrator for MS in your company? c) you shouldn't need to disable security defaults, but you may need to enable this particular user to send email

@Bergi I am the administrator of the workspace. Also, I've tried to enable Authenticated SMTP under admin.microsoft.com > Active Users > no-reply user > Mail > Manage Email Apps. But without luck.
